# flume agent throws debug,what could be the issue?

Tags: hadoop, flume

When i try to run the flume agent, i am getting following statement repeatedly.unless i am stopping the task forcefully it displaying continuously, what could be the issue

please help me out

2013-05-27 03:47:12,517 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:188)] Checking file:/etc/flume-ng/conf![enter image description here][1]/loclog.conf for changes

2013-05-27 03:47:12,517 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:188)] Checking file:/etc/flume-ng/conf![enter image description here][1]/loclog.conf for changes

2013-05-27 03:47:12,517 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:188)] Checking file:/etc/flume-ng/conf![enter image description here][1]/loclog.conf for changes

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour and should be ignored.

Flume automatically checks its config files for changes. If it detects a change it will reconfigure itself with those changes. The DEBUG entries you see above are Flume checking its config file.

Note that the reconfiguration process will not pick up all changes. I've noticed that new sources and sinks will often require a process restart.